# powershell script is not running for calling macro of excel

Tags: powershell

PowerShell script is not running for calling macro of excel.I am calling it as activity in eye share.can anyone please help?

Thanks and Regards,
Nutan Kadam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Not clear how it is implemented with eye share . But the below code works for 
macro calling ;
```

> ```
>  $excel = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application    
>     $wbPersonalXLSB = $excel.workbooks.open("$env:USERPROFILE\Application 
>                        Data\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART\PERSONAL.XLSB")
>     $FilePath = $csvFile
>     $workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($FilePath)
>     $excel.Visible = $true
>     $worksheet = $workbook.worksheets.item(1)
>     $excel.Run("PERSONAL.XLSB!your_macro_name")
>     $workbook.save()
>     $workbook.close()
>     $excel.quit()
> ```